# How to set the Droppable/Draggable Event on the mouse cursor

Tags: drag-and-drop, wicket

I've implemented the Drag-n-Drop effects in Wicket using the Ajax Behavior. If I dragg the Image over the tree nodes, the position of droppable accept is in the middle of image. How to set this position (event) on the cursor?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Also I found it. The solution is:

```
DroppableAjaxBehavior b = new DroppableAjaxBehavior() {
    @Override
    public void onDrop(Component droppedComponent, AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        //do something to handle event
    }
};

b.setTolerance(ToleranceEnum.POINTER);
```